# Date Format With Custom Separators?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

If i do

```
 select to_char(bornDate,'dd-month-yyyy') from workers;
```

I get

```
"01-february -1960"
"12-april    -1964"
"25-september-1955"
"13-december -1963"
"05-november -1967"
"15-march    -1968"
"22-february -1972"
"18-august   -1975"
"09-march    -1975"
"02-march    -1969"
"09-december -1973"
"20-january  -1964"
```

I need to replace the "-" separator with "of". I need dates like this:

```
 01 of february of 1960
```

How can I do it in oracle?

Comment: `select to_char(sysdate,'DD "of" MONTH "of" YYYY') from dual`. All that was required was to lookup the Oracle database [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).

Comment: @Abra - the documentation that you so rightly pointed to explains several more things; please see my answer to see what you missed. MONTH in your suggestion will result in FEBRUARY in the output, when the OP requested lowercase; and without the `fm` modifier, FEBRUARY will be followed by *two* spaces, because the longest month name (September) is nine characters, and February is only eight characters.

Comment: I see that this question has two downvotes. Yet no one cared enough to explain their downvote. I don't see anything wrong with the question, so an explanation would certainly have helped *me* understand the downvotes.

Comment: Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on _stackoverflow_ META. Here is a quote: ___Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer___ I think the first step should be the Oracle documentation. It appears the OP did not search there, hence my down-vote.

Comment: @mathguy my comment was intended to make the OP aware of the Oracle documentation and my hope was that he would visit the link I provided where he would have discovered all the nuances you mentioned in your answer. Your answer probably saved the OP from making the effort to read the documentation thus reinforcing his belief that he just needs to post a question without doing any prior research which is something that is discouraged on SO. (See my comment explaining why I down-voted this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd "of" fmmonth "of" yyyy') as my_date_format
from   dual
;

MY_DATE_FORMAT                                    
-------------------------
07 of february of 2020
```

Notice a few things here. You can insert any boilerplate text within a date format model, by enclosing it in **double**-quotes. Then: use lowercase for the `month` element, if you want the month name in the output to be all-lowercase (which is quite odd, by the way; in English, including American English, month names are always capitalized; perhaps you would like to use `Month` instead of `month` in the format model).

Then: the `fm` modifier before `month` will cause the month name to only take as many characters as needed. The default (without the `fm` modifier) will add spaces after the month name, to make all month names (from january to december) be the same length as the longest name. From the example you posted, you don't want that; you do, indeed, want the result with the `fm` modifier. Of course, you can experiment with removing it and comparing the outputs.

Finally, you could move the fm earlier in the model, like so: `'fmdd "of" month "of" yyyy'`. The result of this is that the day would be shown as `1` instead of `01`. In your question you said you wanted `01` in the output, so the `fm` should come before the `month` element. (Note that if you want both the date AND the month to be in minimal length, you only use `fm` **once**, before `dd`; the modifier acts as a **switch** - once you invoke it, it remains in force until you invoke it a second time.)

Comment: ty for the asnwer i will mark as the correct one but what is exactly dual? in my case should be select to_char(borndate, 'dd "of" fmmonth "of" yyyy') as my_date_format
from my_table dual   ??

Comment: @AndresMachinMoreno - if you work with Oracle at all, you should already know what `dual` is. It's a standard **table** provided by Oracle for a few purposes, one of them being to use it in tests and examples. Run `select * from dual` to see what it contains (as you will see, it is a **very** simple table.) In any case, that has no relevance to the question; you select `from my_table`. (No "dual" at the end!) If your background is in a different database product, please note that in Oracle you can't just "select" an expression, without selecting it **from** some place. `dual` is used for that.